# How to make some fields to be required for SOAP API Requests?

Tags: c#, api, wcf, soap, request

I have made a WCF Service in order to make a SOAP API.
I want to make these fields required: `Username` , `Password` , `ID`

How can I make them to be required fields when a client make a request to the API?

I want to :

- make them required for every API Request , and when the request does not contain one of them to send an ERROR.
- check them in order to see if the client has send the correct Credentials , an if one of them is wrong to send an ERROR.
  **For Example :**
  If their value must be :
- `Username` = user
- `Password` = pass
- `ID` = IdNumber

**This is the code for them so far:**

```
[OperationContract]
Credentials CheckCredentials(Credentials credentials);
```

```
[DataContract]
public class Credentials
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorResult { get; set; }

}
```

```
public Credentials CheckCredentials(Credentials credentialsCheck)
{
    if (credentialsCheck.Username == "user" && 
        credentialsCheck.Password == "pass" && 
        credentialsCheck.ID == "IdNumber")
    {
        credentialsCheck.ErrorResult = "Correct";

        return credentialsCheck;
    }
    else
    {
        credentialsCheck.ErrorResult = "Wrong";

        return credentialsCheck;
    }

}
```

Any other suggestions would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved?

Comment: @DingPeng , no yet ,  I can not understand the process

Comment: Can you use UserName authentication?

Comment: You can get an example of using UserName authentication in this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459

Answer (score 0):

UserName authentication is provided in WCF, which will require the client to provide username and password when calling the service, here is a demo:

Create CustomUserNameValidator class:

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
        {
            public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
            {
                if (null == userName || null == password)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                }

                if (!(userName == "test1" && password == "test1") && !(userName == "test2" && password == "test2"))
                {
                    throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
                }
            }
        }
```

Add the userNameAuthentication node in the configuration file:

```
 <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Microsoft.Samples.UserNamePasswordValidator.CalculatorService+CustomUserNameValidator, service"/>
```

The client needs to provide username and password when calling:

```
  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test1";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test1";
```

If you still need to verify the ID, you need to consider using Custom Token. For how to Create a Custom Token, you can refer to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-custom-token